# Firebase Javascript SDK not retrieving the whole document fields from Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

By the Firestore Web Console I can consult the data, I have the below described document:

```
register (map)
    email: "cadi****r.edu.br" (string)
    isAdmin: true (boolean)
    name: "Sanson " (string)
    uid: "U6bXeb4qVnWU9pd****"
```

When data is retrieved by Javascript (VueJS app) the field **isAdmin** is not retrieved along the other fields:
`console.log(...)`

```
{register: {…}}
register: 
   email: "cadin****r.edu.br"
   name: "Sanson "
   uid: "U6bXeb4qVnWU9p*****"
```

Code Javascript:

```
var db = firebase.firestore()
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser
const doc = await db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();
var data = doc.data();
console.log(data);
console.log( data.register.isAdmin); // Prints `undefined`
```

There is no security rules blocking the field retrieval.

Web Console view:
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code used to create the users documents?

Comment: You trend me to analyze deeper the code, before read the `isAdmin`, indeed I was updating the Doc Data by `db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .set(
          {
            register: {
              uid: user.uid,
              name: user.displayName,
              email: user.email,
            },
          },
          {
            merge: true,
          }
        );`. But there, I am using `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en&authuser=0#update_fields_in_nested_objects) about "Update fields in nested objects":

> Dot notation allows you to update a single nested field without
> overwriting other nested field. If you update a nested field without
> dot notation, you will overwrite the entire map field

So you need to do (untested):

```
db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).set(
  { register.uid: user.uid, register.name: user.displayName, ... },
  { merge: true }         
);
```

Comment: Hey @augusto, did you have time to look at the proposed answer